# Wrapping Docx file with another docx file

Tags: c#, zip, openxml, docx

i trying to find a way to hide a docx file inside other docx for example i have an outside.docx that  written inside hello world , and another file named inside.docx that written hidden info.
i want to embed the file inside so in some condition A for example outside.docx will be shown, 
and in condition B inside.docx will be shown,
i tried several solutions to this problem including:
editing the file with hex editor , and copy the content of outside to wrap the file inside , and changing the jump address at the footer accordingly.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here just an idea, if bmk is set to 1234, content of foo.docx will be used, otherwise "not 1234"

```
{ SET bmk 1234 }
{ IF bmk = 1234 "{ INCLUDETEXT c:\\users\\auser\\foo.docx }" "not 1234" }
```

Use Ctrl-F9 to insert all `{}`

Use absolute file name, the current working directory in Word is tricky.

Comment: this is a nice approach but i am looking for more pragmatically answer acctualy i am so close to figure it out. i will write my solution whenever i finished this.

Comment: yes, in your question there are things which are not clear to me. I have no clue what "jump address at the footer accordingly" means.

Comment: i will try to clarify some things - [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)[link] you can see here at the  End of central directory record (EOCD) at Byte 16 that this is the addres which the word will start reading the central dirctories from. i found a way to hide the docx inside the footer comment field but it can only hide docx files up to 2^16 size, so it doesnt help me much. i hope this clear some things